# How do I fix my Express.js app crashing when I spam requests to the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node.js-fs

Recently, I've been trying to fix an error with my Express.js app that happens when I send so many PUT or PUSH requests to the server. When I send enough requests, It'll break and send 502 HTTP code to the client and logs this on server:

```
RangeError [ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE]: Invalid status code: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
 at JSON.parse(<anonymous>)
 at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
 at ServerResponse.writeHead (node:http_server:343:11)
 at ServerResponse.writeHead (/home/runner/The-Randomists/node_modules/on-headers/index.js:44:26)
 at ServerResponse._implicitHeader (node:_http_server:334:8)
 at writetop (/home/runner/The-Randomists/node_modules/express-session/index.js:276:15)
 at ServerResponse.end (/home/runner/The_Randomists/node_modules/express-session/index.js:356:16)
 at ServerResponse.send (/home/runner/The-Randomists/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:232:10)
 at ServerResponse.sendStatus(/home/runner/The-Randomists/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:375:15) {
 code: 'ERR_HTTP_INVALID_STATUS_CODE'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

This is my current code, I have two routes. I also use express-rate-limit and I am using it to attempt to combat this error, to no avail. Code:

```
app.post('/addPostToTopRatedWithID/:PostID', checkAuth, async (req, res) => {
  try {
      const ID = req.params.PostID;
      const PostsStringed = await fs.promises.readFile('./data/posts.json', 'utf-8'); 
      const TopRatedStringed = await fs.promises.readFile('./data/top-rated.json', 'utf-8');

      const Posts = JSON.parse(PostsStringed); 
      const TopRated = JSON.parse(TopRatedStringed);
      const Post = Posts[ID];
  
      if (!Post) {
        return res.status(404).send('Post not found');
      }

      if (TopRated[ID]) {
        return res.status(409).send('Post already in Top Rated!');
      }

      if (Post.health < 100) {
        return res.status(409).send('Conflict with checks; post aint ready');
      }
  
      const addSync = async () => {
        TopRated[ID] = Post;
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/top-rated.json', JSON.stringify(TopRated));
      }; 
      const removeSync = async () => {
        delete TopRated[ID];
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/top-rated.json', JSON.stringify(TopRated));
      };

      await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const execute = () => {
          removeSync();
          resolve();
        }
        addSync();
    
        setTimeout(execute, 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
      });
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log('Hey if you see this err!')
    await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/dump.json', JSON.stringify({
      dump: err
    }))
  }
})
```

There is another route that might be at fault here too.
here is that route:

```
app.put('/upVotePostWithID/:PostID', checkAuth, async (req, res) => {

  try {
    const ForumID = req.params.PostID;
    const Data = await fs.promises.readFile('./data/posts.json', 'utf-8');
    const Posts = JSON.parse(Data);
    const Post = Posts[ForumID];
    const user = await req.user;
    
    if (!Post) {
      !res.headersSent ? res.status(404).send('Post not found') : null;
    }

    if (Post.likers.indexOf(user.id) !== -1) {
      Post.health -= 1;
      Post.likers.splice(Post.likers.indexOf(user.id), 1);
      Posts[ForumID] = Post;
      const StringifiedPosts = JSON.stringify(Posts);
      try {
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/posts.json', StringifiedPosts);
      }
      catch(err) {
        console.log('Hey if you see this err!')
        await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/dump.json', JSON.stringify({
          dump: err
        }))
      }
      return res.status(409).json({
        message: 'You have already liked this post.',
        health: Post.health
      });
    }
    
    Post.dislikers.indexOf(user.id);
    if (Post.dislikers.indexOf(user.id) !== -1) {
      Post.health += 1
      Post.dislikers.splice(Post.dislikers.indexOf(user.id), 1);
    }
    Post.likers.splice(user.id, 0, user.id);
    
    Post.health += 1;

    Posts[ForumID] = Post;
    
    const StringifiedPosts = JSON.stringify(Posts);

    try {
      await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/posts.json', StringifiedPosts);
    }
    catch(err) {
      console.log('Hey if you see this err!')
      await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/dump.json', JSON.stringify({
        dump: err
      }))
    }
    
    return !res.headersSent ? res.status(200).json({
      id: Post.id,
      health: Post.health
    }) : null;
    
  } 
  catch (err) {
    console.log('Hey if you see this err!')
    await fs.promises.writeFile('./data/dump.json', JSON.stringify({
      dump: err
    }))
  }
  
});
```

Here is the current state of posts.json

```
{"1":{"title":"Hello!","description":"Never gonnan!","author":1,"likers":[],"dislikers":[],"id":2,"health":0}}
```

Here is top-rated.json

```
{}
```

Comment: Please share the full stacktrace. It is important information to determine where exactly the error originates.

Comment: Ok I will do that

Comment: Ok I added all the info I got from the error message.

Comment: I'd guess its either a race condition with the JSON files, or an erroneous `res.status` call, which is being passed garbage.

Comment: Ok. What would I need to do to make sure this bug can't happen?

Comment: can you post the posts.json and toprated.json?

Comment: OK, I'll do that.

Comment: I added the JSON contents to the post